# Watson Knowledge Studio integration with Watson Discovery

Tags: curl, single-sign-on, watson-discovery

I am trying to execute the following curl command that should allow me to obtain the .json file that I need to update and PUT in order to integrate WKS and WDS:  curl -u username@ibm.com:password "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/"env id"/configurations/"config id"?version=2016-12-01" > my_config.json

The curl command works, however, I get a 401 error in the .json file that I am "not authorized".
{ "code" : 401 , "error" : "Not Authorized" , "description" : "2017-07-06T12:07:46-04:00, Error ERCDPLTFRM-INVLDCHR occurred when accessing https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/"env id"/configurations/"config id"?version=2016-12-01, Tran-Id: gateway-dp01-472751002 - " }

I am an IBM employee.  Could this be due to our IBM SSO blue mix requirement?  All help is appreciated as I need this in order to move forward building my code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the username and password are *not* your Bluemix login credentials. When you create a service instance in Bluemix, Bluemix generates credentials for that specific service instance.

In the Bluemix console, https://console.bluemix.net, navigate to your Discovery instance, then, on the left side of the browser window, click on **Service credentials**, then toward the right, click on *View credentials*. The username and password shown there are what you need to use for `curl` or any other API access to this specific Discovery service instance. If you create a second service instance, Discovery or something else, it will have its own service credentials that you'll need to use for that service instance.

Comment: Bruce, thank you!  That was the problem.  No, I have another issue.  I was able to get the my_config.json file and update/save it, but when I PUT it given the requested curl I am receiving a 415 error, unsupported media type.  According to the documentation, it's supposed to accept the .json.      This is what I'm using:  curl -X PUT -u "discovered":"discoverypw"  -H “Content-Type: application/json” -d@my_config.json "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/"envid"/configurations/"configid"?version=2016-12-01"

Comment: @RoseB Can you ask that as a separate question?

Comment: Done, thank you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980996/watson-knowledge-studio-integration-with-watson-discovery