# Watson Knowledge Studio integration with Watson Discovery

Tags: json, curl, watson-discovery

I was able to get the my_config.json file by doing the provided curl statement and update/save it, but when I PUT it given the requested curl I am receiving a 415 error, unsupported media type. According to the documentation, it's supposed to accept the .json. This is what I'm using: curl -X PUT -u "discovered":"discoverypw" -H “Content-Type: application/json” -d@my_config.json

Comment: What you show in the question looks correct. What URL are you using? This works fine for me:

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d@empty.json -X put --user bc4d8e7f-80b9-4aeb-9c42-e1e4221568b3:fake-password https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/0c369fdc-35e3-443a-b6f7-da102b4abd8b/configurations/0d2e411a-a63d-41ef-8602-f2f8361e8911?version=2017-07-08

Comment: curl -X PUT -u 73d5e0f6-6a9e-4502-8ca3-5a2229d65179:password  -H “Content-Type: application/json” -d@my_config.json "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/disc env id/configurations/disc config id?version=2016-12-01"

Comment: Above is what I am doing and I receive the following error:    curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'application'
{
  "code" : 415,
  "error" : "Unsupported Media Type"

Comment: I have tried numerous different adjustments to what I am doing to no avail.

Comment: Ah! "Couldn't resolve host 'application'" means that the quotes around "Content-Type: application/json" didn't work (and `curl` treated that as two separate words, which meant treating the second part `application/json` being the URL). My best guess is that some (or all) of the quotes in your `curl` command line are fancy quotes, sometimes called "smart" quotes. Can you try removing and then replacing each of the quotes with a simple quote (")? Probably need to do that directly in a terminal or in a text oriented editor, not MS Word nor many web applications.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you are trying to update a configuration.
I tried the operation as described at the following page and could not reproduce your problem. I could update my configuration.
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/#replace_configuration